# Falling sand simulation collision detection C++ and SFML

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml, simulator

I could really use some help. I am trying to make a falling sand simulation and have some basic code down, but I can't figure how to do collision detection. Here is my code so far:

```
//SFML Include
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

//Include Vectors
#include <vector>

//Main Loop
int main()
{
    //Window Init
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(720, 480, 32), "Yip Yip Physics", sf::Style::Default);

    //Global Envoirmental Variables
    static float gravity = 0.25;
    static float frict = 3;

    //Particle Structures
    struct Particle
    {
        //Shape
        sf::RectangleShape rect;

        //Cell Position
        sf::Vector2f cell_pos;

        //Vel and frict
        float slide_vel = 3;
        float grv_vel = 0;

        //Init Particle (size, color and origin)
        void init()
        {
            rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(3, 3));
            rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
            rect.setOrigin(rect.getSize());

        }

    };

    //Particle Setup
    std::vector<Particle> particles;

    //Window Loop
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        //Update
        if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left))
        {
            //Make and Position Particle
            Particle part;
            part.rect.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)));

            //Initalize the Particle and add to vector
            part.init();
            particles.push_back(part);

       
        }

        //Pixel Update
        for (auto& p : particles)
        {

            //Draw in window
            window.draw(p.rect);

        }

        //Display
        window.display();

        //Event Variable
        sf::Event event;

        //Window Event System 
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            //Close Window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();

            }
            
        }

        //Window Clear
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    }

    //Return 0
    return 0;
}
```

The code works in making the particles, putting them in a vector and drawing them to the screen, but I don't know where to go for collision. I don't know where to look and would really appreciate help on it or direction on where to find it. I have heard a bit about cellular automata but have no idea how to do it or if it's the best option.

Comment: Collision detection can be easy and it can be hard. If you have a bunch of static objects, just iterate through them and check if they collide (easy). If you have a bunch of objects in motion and you need to determine if they will collide within one time step of your simulation (difficult), then you have a number of equations to solve for each object and every other object and their collision response will then impact the other objects - doing that right is *hard* and computationally expensive. You may want to cheat somewhere if you don't need 100% physics accuracy.

Comment: Here's something that may get you started: [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php?print=1)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check that out.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you read all of that article, it is very good and helped me a lot years ago when I was struggling with similar problems.

Comment: I will, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how falling sand simulations are usually done!
they are very similar to cellular automata.
normally you would implement them by storing your world in a 2d array and draw the particles by plotting pixels on a framebuffer.
This prevents your simulation's performance from dropping (instead of O(n^2) you get O(n)) and also improves rendering performance (instead of O(n), you get O(1) (blitting a framebuffer is a constant-time operation))

you can get *a lot* of helpful information by just googling the topic!